# how to modify the active region highlighting color

Tags: init-file, display, region, coloring

Gray text highlighting no longer works on my Debian/stretch system. While this is particularly annoying in Emacs, it's not a specific Emacs problem; gray background is also gone from other applications, including the web browser. Therefore I asked for help at  [Unix SO](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252706/gray-highlighting-is-gone).

I do however have an Emacs-specific question: Are there ways of active-region highlighting other than gray background? I would like to try them out in order to narrow down the gray-background-is-gone bug.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684579/how-do-i-change-the-highlight-color-for-selected-text-with-emacs-deftheme) might help you out.

Comment: Thank you, this fully answers my question. If you repost it as an answer, I'll accept it at once.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. :)

Comment: FWIW, I think this question is a duplicate, but I don't have time to search for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `region` face. Put this in your `.emacs` file and change `#666` to any color you want:

```
(set-face-attribute 'region nil :background "#666")
```

You could also then change the font color to make it more readable. E.g. to white

```
(set-face-attribute 'region nil :background "#666" :foreground "#ffffff")
```

Sources: [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684579/how-do-i-change-the-highlight-color-for-selected-text-with-emacs-deftheme) answered by [tungd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/401539/tungd) and [Philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1752229/philippe).